# Is this a common/bug on this PPPoE setting for Cisco ASA 5505?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

We have to change the way the firewall setup due to we've changed the internet provider.

The way we setup we have ADSL modem and we have to do a full bridge mode and the firewall configuration has to change from Static IP to Use PPPoE option on Outside interface with PPPoE username and password, CHAP authentication, WAN IP and WAN subnet mask. [See the attachment]

It's been working ok with the use of PPPoE option however the issue is that if we un-plug the power cable of the firewall. This "Outside" interface turned to blank - NO WAN IP, PPPoE username and password. So basically, we have to retype this information again.

Is this common or a bug? Any ideas?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

On most CISCO equipment,  when you make a configuration change,  you are making it to the running config.  If you restart the device,  it goes back to the last Written Config.  If you did not write the change to the Written Config, then pulling the power would do a reboot, and you would have to redo the change.

Comment: Yeah, `write mem` is your friend.